# Remove wp_add_inline_style

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

Is there a way to remove styles added with wp_add_inline_style?

I noticed if I call wp_add_inline_style multiple times, it just keeps adding style, it does not overwrite what was added before.

The plugin is adding styles:

```
$inline_css = '#selector{
    color:red;
}';
wp_add_inline_style($style, $inline_css);
```

If I do this again:

```
$inline_css = '#other-selector{
    color:blue;
}';
wp_add_inline_style($style, $inline_css);
```

It will just append those css, I would like to clear css before calling wp_add_inline_style again.

Comment: Can you clarify why/where you want to remove them? i.e is a plugin adding it and you want to remove it in your theme?

Comment: Yes, I am writing a plugin which is using wp_add_inline_style. The only thing that I can think of is to use jquery to empty style tag generated by wp_add_inline_style. And I am not sure if this will achieve the same thing  even if I manage to implement it.

Comment: But why do you need to remove it after you've added it? Can't you just not add it? I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have like a backend configurator where user can choose some styles for a given preset, so I am adding some styles in the page, then later when I change to other preset, I need to change these styles to something else. I tried wp_dequeue_style($style); inbetween but its not helping.

Answer (score 9):

### Remove styles added with `wp_add_inline_style()`

If we want to keep the `custom-style-css` but only remove the `custom-style-inline-css`, then we can try e.g.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', function()
{
    // Remove previous inline style
    wp_styles()->add_data( 'custom-style', 'after', '' );    

} );
```

where `after` is data key for the inline style corresponding to the `custom-style` handler.

There is exists a wrapper for `wp_styles()->add_data()`, namely [`wp_style_add_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_style_add_data/).

We could then define the helper function:

```
function wpse_remove_inline_style( $handler )
{
       wp_style_is( $handler, 'enqueued' ) 
    && wp_style_add_data( $handler, 'after', '' );
}
```

and use it like:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', function()
{
    // Remove previous inline style
    wpse_remove_inline_style( 'custom-style' );    

} );
```

I'm skipping the `function_exists` check here.

To override the inline-style, added by another plugin, with our own:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', function()
{
    // Remove previous inline style
    wpse_remove_inline_style( 'custom-style' );    

    // New inline style
    $custom_css = ".mycolor{
        background: {blue};
    }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );

} );
```

### Note

The reason why it doesn't work to override previous inline style with `wp_add_inline_style()` is because the `WP_Style::add_inline_style()` appends each incoming CSS string into an array. Internally it uses `WP_Style::add_data()` to store the accumulated CSS. Here we are using it to overcome the *appending* restriction of `wp_add_inline_style()`.

Comment: Yes, I want to only remove styles added with wp_add_inline_style, not those added with wp_enqueue_style, before I add new ones. I will check provided solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't test it, I had to abandon this because of some other project changes.

Comment: Is this meant as putting the first three scripts to `functions.php` as they are should remove any inline css? Or do we need to identify which inline script to remove? If first, doesn't seem to work, if second, how do I know such identifier?

Comment: This targets a specific script with a given handler/identifier. One can find the handler from the enqueue code or from the script tag in the page's HTML. Here the demo handler is `'custom-style'`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into `wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php` core file I found a filter to use:

```
add_action("print_styles_array", function( $styles ) { 
    $my_handle = "custom-style"; // your custom handle here, the one declared as $style in question
    if ( !empty( $styles ) ) {
        foreach ( $styles as $i => $style ) {
            if ( $my_handle === $style ) {
                unset( $styles[$i] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $styles;
});
```

Note that this will remove all inline styles processed by the handle name.