# Remove inline css added by wp_add_inline_css

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am creating a child theme. I noticed my parent theme is adding some inline CSS in its functions.php:

```
wp_add_inline_style( 'persona-style-css', $custom_css );
```

Since I cannot change some values there, is it possible to dequeue it? I have tried to dequeue it using `wp_dequeue_style ('persona-style-css')` but it didn't really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. How exactly did you use `wp_dequeue_style` and it didn't work? Did you use it inside the same hook that the parent is using to enqueue it with a higher priority?

Comment: Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231821/43098

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `wp_add_inline_css` is fired within an action you can use `remove_action` with the same parameters.

You also might use `wp_enqueue_scripts` action to dequeue any scripts or styles in a proper way. But, inline style are not included in the `$wp_styles` global, you can unset them with the action `print_styles_array`, you need to know the handle name to unset it.

Hope it gives you some hints to make it works.

Comment: `print_styles_array` lists only non-inline queue (same as `$wp_styles`) too.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
function wp_force_remove_style(){

add_filter( 'print_styles_array', function($styles) {

    #DEBUG: Show all registered styles
    //print_r($styles);
    //die();

    #Set styles to remove
    $styles_to_remove = array('persona-style-css');

    if(is_array($styles) AND count($styles) > 0){

        foreach($styles AS $key => $code){

            if(in_array($code, $styles_to_remove)){

                unset($styles[$key]);

            }

        }

    }

    return $styles;

    }); 

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_force_remove_style', 99);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't walk through styles added by `wp_add_inline_css()` as asked, only through styles added by `wp_enqueue_script()`